# Kubernetes Job with single Pod vs single Pod with restart policy OnFailure

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

What are the benefits of a Job with single Pod over just a single Pod with restart policy OnFailure to reliably execute once in kubernetes?

As discussed in [Job being constanly recreated despite RestartPolicy: Never](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20255), in case of a Job a new Pod will be created endlessly in case container returned non-zero status. The same applies to a single OnFailure Pod, only this time no new pods are created which is even cleaner.

What are the cons and pros of either approach? Can Pod restart parameters, such as restart delay, or number of retry attempts can be controlled in either case?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that if a Job doesn't complete because the node that its pod was on went offline for some reason, then a new pod will be created to run on a different node. If a single pod doesn't complete because its node became unavailable, it won't be rescheduled onto a different node.

Comment: What happens to a single pod if the node becomes available again? Will it be re-executed?

Comment: Once a Pod is scheduled to a machine it will be assigned to that machine until it finishes or until it is deleted.  If a node disappears, a timeout starts, and at the end of the timeout, any pods assigned to the node are deleted.  So if the node comes back before the timeout, it will find the pod still assigned and restart it.  If the node comes back after the timeout, it will not find the pod at all.